# Confidence interval for exponential smoothing forecast

Tags: intervals, smoothing, exponential, forecasting

I'm using exponential smoothing (Brown's method) for forecasting. 
The forecast can be calculated for one or more steps (time intervals).
Is there any way to calculate confidence intervals for such prognosis (ex-ante)?

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question for `math.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Should this be on http://stats.stackexchange.com/